# Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in 1

Tags: php, destructor

first sorry for my english:) you tell my why i have this warning when i call magic method __destructor(), i don't think that is scope of property connex, help my...thank you to all!

```
<?php

class Connect{

 protected $user;
 protected $pass;
 protected $host;
 protected $db;
 protected $query;
 protected $result;
 private $connex;


 function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$database){

  $this->host=$host;
  $this->user=$user;
  $this->pass=$pass;
  $this->db=$database;



  // connesione al database

  $this->connex = new mysqli("$this->host", "$this->user", "$this->pass", "$this->db");
  if ($this->connex->connect_errno) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->connect_errno . ") " . $this->connect_error;
  }
  // echo 'connessione stabilita' . "\n";

 }  


function __destruct(){
 mysqli_close($this->connex);
 $this->connex = null; 
}


}



$ist = new Connect("localhost","root","","mio");
$ist->__destruct();
```

Comment: The problem: you call the destructor manually, then it gets called automatically, and $this->connex is null by this time.

Comment: i understand the problem, but how can i solve it? thank you!

Comment: Simply remove your manual call to the destructor.

Comment: but the distructor will be call even in automatically!? it's even wrong call it manually? thank's

Comment: Yes, it will be called automatically when your object is freed.